# WordPress query by taxonomy not working

Tags: wordpress

I have a basic WordPress loop which works fine and outputs posts until I try to add a taxonomy argument to the loop.  Once I add that to the loop it stops outputting anything at all, yet gives no PHP errors.  The loop is below.

```
<?php 
    $newsLoop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'news&events', 'taxonomy' => 'postcategory', 'term' => 'featured',  'posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC'));
    while ( $newsLoop->have_posts() ) : $newsLoop->the_post();
?>

<div class="newsEvent">

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>

</div> 

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I have tried removing the post type argument all together and just querying the taxonomy, no luck there either.  Is there something I am missing here or not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on something similar a few weeks ago and here's what I have for you:

in Functions.php: (to register the taxonomy).

```
$args = array(
      'hierarchical'      => true,
      'labels'            => $labels,
      'show_ui'           => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'query_var'         => true,
      'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'news-category' ),
    );
 register_taxonomy( 'news-tax', array( 'news&events' ), $args );
```

Now the query:

```
<?php $args = array( 'news-tax' => 'postcategory', 'post_type' => 'news&events', 'orderby' => 'post_date','order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
```

Let me know if this works! Also, were you able to successfully query 'news&events' without any taxonomies? maybe the &amp is causing an issue? Either way, I tried many ways and the above worked seamlessly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `tax_query` parameter:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news&events',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'postcategory',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'featured'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$newsLoop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Check the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: I had actually tried this as well.  Same result.  Also, this is not a necessity when querying by taxonomy.  It's optional for more complex taxonomy queries.

Comment: Did you double check your values? Did you maybe intend to query `post_type => array( 'news', 'events' )`?

Comment: I have checked all values multiple times.  The post type is calls News & Events, so that query is correct.  This is very odd behavior, the query works great until I introduce any sort of taxonomy arguments.

Comment: maybe a `pre_get_posts` somewhere in your code influencing the query?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work with any custom taxonomy in any custom post type.  Very stumped with it for sure, as it should be able to be done.